# MSBuild Fails to remove Binaries directory

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild, build-process

I am building two solutions with MSBuild:

```
<ItemGroup> 
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/HostASPX/SolutionA.sln"/>    
    <SolutionToBuild Include="$(BuildProjectFolderPath)/../Installer/SolutionB.sln"/>     
  </ItemGroup>
```

It seems that this build fails with the error message:

> Unable to remove directory "c:\TeamBuild\Team Solutions\Solution\Binaries". The directory is not empty.

It appears that MSBuild creates this 'Binaries' directory by default and the build passes. When I build again the build fails with the above message. If I try a 3rd build.. it works again.

Can someone tell me how to ensure that his folder is deleted/overwritten each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You sure there isn't an [observer effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)) at play? i.e., something isn't locking the directory like explorer.exe :P

You can rule it out by using `\\live.sysinternals.com\procmon.exe` (to find out who is doing what to the dir) and procexp (to find out who is locking it).

Comment: @Nick I'm having the same issue what was causing it in the end

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink , you mean the observer effect? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)

Comment: @juFo Yes, what is the word for using words I dont understand again :) Fixed.

Comment: @RubenBartelink I don't understand them either but Wikipedia told me it was wrong ;-p

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem of **"Unable to remove directory ... the directory is not empty"** while running a target that looks something like this:

```
 <Target Name="CleanFiles"
    DependsOnTargets="Prepare_Files"
    Inputs="@(Files->'%(OutputPath)'->Distinct())"
    Outputs="_Non_Existent_Item_To_Batch_">

    <ItemGroup>
      <DirsToDelete Include="@(Files->'%(OutputPath)'->Distinct())"/>      
    </ItemGroup>

    <RemoveDir Directories="@(DirsToDelete)"/>

  </Target>
```

Occasionally it worked fine and deleted the directories, but often I got the error above.

Eventually I found out that **MSBuild itself is locking the files**, beacuase they appear on the target's "Inputs", and not unlocking them in time for RemoveDir to delete them.
Changing the above to:

```
 <Target Name="CleanFiles"
    DependsOnTargets="Prepare_Files">

    <ItemGroup>
      <DirsToDelete Include="@(Files->'%(OutputPath)'->Distinct())"/>      
    </ItemGroup>

    <RemoveDir Directories="@(DirsToDelete)"/>

  </Target>
```

seems to solve the problem.

It's still OK to delete all directories always since RemoveDir skips non-existent directories and does not report an error.